# how to flip the X for all elements including video/div/iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I applied `-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);`, but its only applying into video element and ignoring all the other elements such as div, image, iframe.

Comment: What about showing some code dude!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by flip you mean mirror, use:

```
body {-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o634r6p0/)

If you mean rotate 180°, use:

```
body {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zh0f3L8j/1/)

Both of these will mirror/rotate everything within the `<body>` tag. If you want to only do it to specific elements, apply a class to those elements:

```
// css
.mirrored {-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);}    

// html
<div class="mirrored">Hello World</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3frz94a/)